# integrating android chromecast application with a login page results in NullPointerException (NPE)

Tags: java, android, android-intent, google-cast

I have changed the CastVideos Android application (https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android) to integrate a login page. Conceptually, instead of setting VideoBrowserActivity to be the main activity that launches when the app starts, I set my own login activity. My AndroidManifest.xml looks something like the following (details omitted).

```
<activity android:name="com.x.y.z.LoginActivity"
 android:noHistory="true">
 <intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
 </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name="com.x.y.z.VideoBrowserActivity">
</activity>
```

Please note the android:noHistory="true" attribute for the LoginActivity. After a user logs into my application, I don't want the user to be able to get back to this activity by pressing the back button.

When a user successfully logs in, the VideoBrowserActivity (unaltered, except for package name) is started.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, com.x.y.z.VideoBrowserActivity);
startActivity(intent);
```

I then press the back button, and I immediately exit the app and to the home screen. This behavior is what I expect. However, when I long press the home button to get a list of apps, I get the message: Unfortunately, APP has stopped.

LogCat shows the following NPE.

```
04-25 05:58:11.745: E/AndroidRuntime(8305): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-25 05:58:11.745: E/AndroidRuntime(8305): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-25 05:58:11.745: E/AndroidRuntime(8305):     at com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.cast.VideoCastManager$UpdateNotificationHandlerCallback.handleMessage(VideoCastManager.java:2000)
04-25 05:58:11.745: E/AndroidRuntime(8305):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-25 05:58:11.745: E/AndroidRuntime(8305):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-25 05:58:11.745: E/AndroidRuntime(8305):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
04-25 05:58:11.745: E/AndroidRuntime(8305):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-25 05:58:11.745: E/AndroidRuntime(8305):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-25 05:58:11.745: E/AndroidRuntime(8305):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
04-25 05:58:11.745: E/AndroidRuntime(8305):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
04-25 05:58:11.745: E/AndroidRuntime(8305):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any ideas on how to avoid this NPE? Or any better ideas on how to get integrate a login page with ChromeCast?

Actually, I tested pressing the back button on the CastVideos app as-is from GitHub, and the same NPE is thrown. So, this problem is not just with my integration.

I also added logic to detect when the back button is pressed as follows, but the NPE does not go away.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
 if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
        this.finish();
    }
}
```

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this with CastVideos-android. What phone/android version are you using?

Comment: I am using the Samsung Galaxy S4.